# Date is getting changed while parsing

Tags: java, date

In the following code the date is getting changed while parsing:
In particular the minutes are getting increased by 5 mins.
Why is this happening?

```
String inputDate="2016-12-01T16:30:59.264448";             
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date parsedTimeStamp=null;

if(!inputDate.contains(".")){
     try {
           parsedTimeStamp = dateFormat1.parse(inputDate.replace("T", " "));
     } catch (ParseException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
}else{
     try {
    parsedTimeStamp = dateFormat.parse(inputDate.replace("T", " "));

     } catch (ParseException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
System.out.println("Date-->"+parsedTimeStamp);
```

Comment: inputDate ? where is it?

Comment: 2016-12-01T16:30:59.264448

Comment: seems by `inputDate` you mean the string `parsedInput`, is this just a typo or inputDate is a different variable ?

Comment: yep that was a mistake...rectified,please look into it now..

Comment: 264448ms is 4.40 minutes, so I believe it is parsed as milliseconds but translated to the extra minutes you get

Comment: @Aaron why not post it as an answer?

Comment: To investigate such errors you should `dateFormat.setLenient(false)` as it will throw an exception if the format / input is wrong. `264448` can't be a valid value for milliseconds (must be in the range of 0-999).

Comment: @Aaron any way i can store it as it is. and then print also the exact same value.

Comment: @user7456985 at worst you could trim the last 3 chars from the string, but there should be a more integrated way to do that...

Comment: actually i dont want to trim that.need all 6 digits exactly the same.

Comment: @user7456985 you mean you need to parse the first 3 chars as milliseconds and the next 3 as microseconds?

Comment: @SubOptimal any way i can store it as it is. and then print also the exact same value.

Comment: no all as millisec

Comment: @user7456985 then your "five more minutes" result is correct. Why would you want to keep a more-than-1000 number of milliseconds?

Comment: 264448ms is 448ms + 264 seconds = 448ms + 4min + 24sec

Comment: your point is valid but its just the requirement is like that. i have to keep it the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strong requirement to preserve microsecond precision in your input then you might consider the new class `java.time.LocalDateTime` introduced in Java-8 which can store up to nanoseconds. And your input does not contain any zone or offset information so `LocalDateTime` is the best choice as type. Example using just ONE formatter:

```
String input1 = "2016-12-01T16:30:59.264448";
String input2 = "2016-12-01T16:30:59";

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSS]");

LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(input1, dtf); // 2016-12-01T16:30:59.264448
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(input2, dtf); // 2016-12-01T16:30:59
```

You can also use following bridge to old `Date`-type (legacy-API):

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from(ldt1.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Answer (score 2):

2 Things , If you look at the Documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (Java 8 or 7), especially the part about "Date and Time Patterns", you notice

> H Hour in day (0-23)
>   h Hour in am/pm (1-12)

So you should consider using the below for the

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and those Milliseconds that you provide are converted to seconds / minutes and hence the result.

Comment: any way i can store it as it is. and then print also the exact same value

Comment: One correction though. `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse microseconds, hence use SSS instead of SSSSSS.